# Dissecting a permutation algorithm in swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I was looking for a string permutation algorithm and I found this one.

```
    import Foundation

    func permuteHelper(_ str:String, _ chosen:String){
        var chosen = chosen
        var str = str
        if str.count == 0 {
            print(chosen)
        } else {
            for index in str.indices {
                //choose
                let charac = str[index]
                chosen.append(charac)
                str.remove(at: index)
                // explore
                print("call recursion")
                permuteHelper(str, chosen)
                print("return from recursion")
                //unchoose
                str.insert(charac, at: index)
                chosen.removeLast()
            }
        }
    }

    func permute(_ str:String){
        permuteHelper(str, "")
    }

    var str = "ABC"
    permute(str)
```

I run it and then it prints the execution:

```
call recursion
call recursion
call recursion
ABC
return from recursion
return from recursion
call recursion
call recursion
ACB
return from recursion
return from recursion
return from recursion
call recursion
call recursion
call recursion
BAC
return from recursion
return from recursion
call recursion
call recursion
BCA
return from recursion
return from recursion
return from recursion
call recursion
call recursion
call recursion
CAB
return from recursion
return from recursion
call recursion
call recursion
CBA
return from recursion
return from recursion
return from recursion
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

In the first 8 lines it has the *first cycle* with the result: `ABC`. It looks stranger to me that it make `3` `call recursion`, shows the result and then complete `2` `return from recursion` and starts a new cycle.

**My question is:**

It is not suppose to came back to *third* `return from recursion` before starts a new cycle?

**==>> UPDATE**

After add a level parameter in permuteHelper `func permuteHelper(_ str:String, _ chosen:String, _ level:Int)` as Martin R suggested. It looks like the algorithm complete a cycle after print two permutations. As follow:

```
call recursion Level: 1
call recursion Level: 2
call recursion Level: 3
ABC
return from recursion Level: 3
return from recursion Level: 2
call recursion Level: 2
call recursion Level: 3
ACB
return from recursion Level: 3
return from recursion Level: 2
return from recursion Level: 1
call recursion Level: 1
call recursion Level: 2
call recursion Level: 3
BAC
return from recursion Level: 3
return from recursion Level: 2
call recursion Level: 2
call recursion Level: 3
BCA
return from recursion Level: 3
return from recursion Level: 2
return from recursion Level: 1
call recursion Level: 1
call recursion Level: 2
call recursion Level: 3
CAB
return from recursion Level: 3
return from recursion Level: 2
call recursion Level: 2
call recursion Level: 3
CBA
return from recursion Level: 3
return from recursion Level: 2
return from recursion Level: 1
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Add a `level: Int` parameter to your helper function, print it in your debug output, and increase it when the function calls itself recursively: `permuteHelper(str, chosen, level + 1)`  – Then you should see how the recursion works. If that does not help: The *debugger* is your friend!

Comment: Thanks for the help Martin !  I've just add the level parameter and update the question. So, it looks like that the cycle defines the first character that will be printed. What do you think?

Comment: much better to iterate the string indices instead of repeatedly offsetting from the start index         `for index in str.indices {
            let charac = str[index]
            chosen.append(charac)
            str.remove(at: index)
            permuteHelper(str, chosen)
            str.insert(charac, at: index)
            chosen.removeLast()
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is not suppose to came back to third return from recursion before starts a new cycle?

No. The two returns and two calls at the beginning are while the algorithm is generating the permutations for the string `BC` (having selected `A` at the top level).

It takes three recursions to pick the first letter for each of the permutations of `ABC` To pick the second letter, it requires two recursions for the two characters of the original string minus the first picked character. To pick the third letter, it takes one recursion, because there is only a one character string to pick it from.

Unfortunately, the waters are muddied by the fact that you are doing some of the work in a loop and your "call recursion" diagnostic is in the loop. So when `string` is more than one character long, you get multiple diagnostics at the same level.